# What is the gene corresponding to MIR382 RNA molecule?

Tags: molecular-biology, gene-expression, rna, gene

Where can I find information such as this?

Comment: Did you try a Google search first before asking here? We ask that you thoroughly research your question and try to answer it yourself before asking here. Otherwise, the post may be downvoted and/or closed.

Comment: I did. Look at the comments in the answer, which I couldn't find from google search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You find such information on ncbi gene (or ensembl gene)

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/494331

Note that Mir 382 still only is provisional.

Comment: So where's the gene?

Comment: The section on genomic context lists the physical location of the entrez gene 494331 which is the gene encoding Mir 382 in humans

Comment: Does it not give a specific name as to what gene it is?

Comment: The second line at the top has the entry for "Official Full Name". In this case the name of the gene is "microRNA 382" . For the human gene, this name comes from HGNC, which is the official naming committee of human genes. (see the entry on "provided by"). For additional non-standardized names you might also want to see the "also known as" and "Summary" fields at ncbi gene (which is basically one of the two major official resources for genes)